# jquery proper code running only partially

Tags: jquery

I had to made this question, because I'm completelly not understanding behauviour of- rather simple- code. It seems just silly.

I used this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/GhVkx/

like this `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Markers -->
<script src="js/markers.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="image-wrapper" data-captions='{"coords": [{"top":180,"left":180,"text":"iMac 1"},{"top":250,"left":300,"text":"iMac 2"}]}'>
    <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-1vD_YbYlhB8/T1Mrp1RbCzI/AAAAAAAAA3o/D-78syV8tQQ/s347/web-agency-company.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Where js/markers.js is pure javascript code from mentioned page, and style.css is pure css code, also from this page.

Jquery, JS and CSS are loading properly.

Tested code runned properly once (!), then after some changes, markers are displayed but clicking on them are not making any effects. 
I reverted all the changes and tried pure code again on different files, but still effect is the same- no reaction on clicking markers!

I was trying on Firefox and Chrome, same behauviour.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT: this code was working on the older version of jQuery- 1.8.3, not on modern versions. Thanks for help for each of the commenters.**

Comment: work fine for the jsfiddle that you provide, the mark did expand , maybe try to clear the browser cache?

Comment: Is your markers.js being loaded as resource?

Comment: @Arcturus Yes, they do! I would even say, they are loading properly, because if I will corrupt reference to them, not even the marker icons are loading.

Comment: @Se0ng11 I tried, didn't worked :(

Comment: Does the jsFiddle also not work on your pc?

Comment: @Arcturus jsFiddle page, to which I gave link, works proper for me. But! When I created my own fiddle with same, copied code- it does not!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the working fiddle and the HTML in the question is in the version of jQuery. Your code uses the deprecated `.live()` method, which was [removed in jQuery version 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/). The fiddle uses version 1.8, your question mentions 1.11.

Use the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.live()`.